# Visual Flow Community user access

Tags: community, custom-button, partner-communities, visual-flows

I have a custom button that launches a visual flow which I have modified to work in my Partner Community (called 'Partner Community'). The name of the flow is 'Resubmit_Lead' I am unsure as to why the below code does not work. Any ideas? I get the error that says 'URL Does not exist...'

```
/Partner_Community/apex/Resubmit_Lead?varLeadId={!Lead.Id}&retURL={!Lead.Id}
```

Answer (score 2):

These are the instructions from the [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_external.htm):

> **Distribute a Flow to External Users**
>
> Let external users run your flow by adding the flow to a Visualforce
>   page and distributing that page externally. For example, through a
>   Force.com site, Customer Portal, or Partner Portal.
>
> To add a flow to a Visualforce page, embed it by using the
>   <`flow:interview`> component.
>
> 1. Find the flow’s unique name.
>
>    - From Setup, enter Flows in the Quick Find box, then select Flows.
>    - Click the name of the flow.
>    - Copy the unique name of the flow.
> 2. From Setup, enter Visualforce Pages in the Quick Find box, then select Visualforce Pages.
> 3. Define a new Visualforce page, or open an existing one.
> 4. Add the <`flow:interview`> component somewhere between the <`apex:page`> tags.
> 5. Set the name attribute to the unique name of the flow.  If the flow is from a managed package, the name attribute must be in this
>      format: `namespace.flowuniquename`.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <apex:page>
>     <flow:interview name="flowuniquename"/>
> </apex:page>
> ```
>
> 6. Click Save.
> 7. Restrict which users can access the Visualforce page. Any external users with access to the Visualforce page can run the embedded flow.
>
>    - Click Visualforce Pages.
>    - Click Security next to your Visualforce page.
>    - Move all the appropriate profiles from Available Profiles to Enabled Profiles by using the add and remove buttons.
>    - Click Save.
> 8. Distribute your Visualforce page by taking one of these actions.
>
>    - Add the Visualforce page to your Force.com site.
>    - Define a custom Visualforce tab by using the Visualforce page, and then add that tab to your portal or community.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I have just embedded my Flow in a Visualforce page and passed in the parameters that way. I believe that Community users cannot access the Flow directly unless it is embedded in a page. [Here](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_flows_setting_values.htm) is a good explanation of how to do the embedding. The bonus of having it on a Visualforce page is you can make it publicly available via Sites.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to avoid using a vf page so afraid this is not an option. Although Partner Users can't get granted the permission on the profile level to access Flow, they can still run them. (Sounds silly but it does work for them!)